# I need help in iphone memory management

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I am developing application which is using many photos so definitely it crashes though i released the images as some part is shown in following code

```
 -(void)addScrollView{
[self selectData];


scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 300, 160)];
int counter=10;
float y=10.0f;
int fullLength=[photoArray count];
int horizontal=(fullLength/2)*80;
int vertical=160;
int c1=1;
for(int c=0;c<[photoArray count];c++){
    PhotoData *d=[photoArray objectAtIndex:c];
    //NSLog(d.photoPath);
    if(c==fullLength/2  &&c1<3){
        counter=10;
        y=y+80.0f;
        c1++;

    }
    UIImage *img1=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:d.photoPath];
    UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.tag=d.photoId;

    //set the button states you want the image to show up for
    [button setBackgroundImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(counter, y, 70.0, 70.0)];

    //create the touch event target, i am calling the 'productImagePressed' method
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteImage:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollView addSubview:button];
    counter=counter+80.0f;
    [img1 release];
    [button release];

}
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(horizontal, vertical)];


[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView release];

}
```

Dealloc is also not called because i am using tabbased application.
So please help how can solve this memory management issue.

Comment: Where does it crash? What kind of crash?

Comment: Err…that seems to have nothing to do with your code or a memory management issue. Can you clarify/expand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue is what you mentioned—that you might have too many images or objects loaded. In that case, you may want to save some data to a file behind the scenes, and do fetches as needed. Maybe instead of storing all the objects in photoArray, write to a file (you could even just write the file path to a file) and batch load ten or so at a time, rather than all of them. Without more info though, there's not much more I can say.